# Ajax xMlHttpRequest.responseText not display what I set (very strange!)

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-ajax

I have a standard Ajax call with "Success" and "error". The error part is as straightforward as:

```
error: function (xMlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 errorLabel.text("ERROR:  " + xMlHttpRequest.responseText); },
```

And in my C# backend, I saw someone recommend to use these code:

```
Response.StatusCode = 409; //as long as not 200
Response.Clear();
Response.Write(msg);
Response.End();
```

My errorLabel successfully display xMlHttpRequest.responseText after validation ON MY LOCAL DEV MACHINE.

However when I publish everything to a WINDOWS 2012 SERVER, there is no customized 'msg' in xMlHttpRequest.responseText anymore. Instead I got "**The page was not displayed because there was a conflict**" in responseText. (I could understand that status code 409 means there is a conflict.)

So how come it will perform like that when on a server ?? My own error message seems to have been replaced!

Thanks a lot!

***********************  C# Code ******************

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    if (someconditiontrue)
    {
       return Json(new {value1=xxxx, value2=yyy})
    }
    else
    {
       Response.StatusCode = 409; //as long as not 200
       Response.Clear();
       Response.Write("my customized error message");
       Response.End();
    }

    return Content(string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: If possible try to post your complete c# backend..

Comment: Hi  Guruprasad Rao, I added

Comment: And what is the `dataType` you are expecting from `ajax`.??

Comment: I didn't explicitly mentioned in ajax block. When succeed, I could get e.g. "result.value1" and "result.value2". When error happens, I just want to display xMlHttpRequest.responseText -- "my customized error message". And it works on my local dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it around by not using "error" as returned result. Instead I still use Json { error = "my customized error message") object as result, and display corresponding validation message in "success: function(result){....}" block.